# FPC pointer operation to Delphi adjustent

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, freepascal, delphi-5

I'm trying to adjust some code to Delphi:

https://github.com/cooljeanius/doublecmd/blob/master/src/platform/win/ugdiplus.pas

The original function (I have removed the irrelevant code):

```
{$mode objfpc}
// ...
function GetBitmapFromARGBPixels(graphics: GPGRAPHICS; pixels: LPBYTE; Width, Height: Integer): GPBITMAP;
var
  pSrc, pDst: LPDWORD;
begin
  // ...
  pSrc := LPDWORD(pixels);
  pDst := LPDWORD(bmData.Scan0);
  // Pixels retrieved by GetDIBits are bottom-up, left-right.
  for x := 0 to Width - 1 do
    for y := 0 to Height - 1 do            
      pDst[(Height - 1 - y) * Width + x] := pSrc[y * Width + x];
  GdipBitmapUnlockBits(Result, @bmData);
end;
```

How do I translate this line correctly? (`pSrc, pDst` are `LPDWORD`):

```
pDst[(Height - 1 - y) * Width + x] := pSrc[y * Width + x];
```

Delphi compiler shows error: `[Error] Unit1.pas(802): Array type required`

I have tried:

```
type
  _LPDWORD = ^_DWORD;
  _DWORD = array[0..0] of DWORD;
...
_LPDWORD(pDst)^[(Height - 1 - y) * Width + x] := _LPDWORD(pSrc)^[y * Width + x];
```

I'm not sure if that is correct?

Or maybe this?:

```
PByte(Cardinal(pDst) + (Height - 1 - y) * Width + x)^ := PByte(Cardinal(pSrc) + y * Width + x)^;
```

Comment: Translate to what ? How ? What is the problem ?

Comment: @TLama, pSrc and pDst are pointers. compiler tells me that `[Error] Unit1.pas(802): Array type required`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of this:

```
function GetBitmapFromARGBPixels(graphics: GPGRAPHICS; pixels: LPBYTE; Width, Height: Integer): GPBITMAP;
const
  MaxArraySize = MaxInt div sizeof(DWord);
type
  TLongDWordArray = array[0..pred(MaxArraySize)] of DWord;
  PLongDWordArray = ^TLongDWordArray;
var
  pSrc, pDst: PLongDWordArray;
begin
  // ...
```

Comment: with `pSrc := PLongDWordArray(pixels);
  pDst := PLongDWordArray(bmData.Scan0);` assignment?

Comment: Yes, exactly - I should have included that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest way to tackle this in Delphi is to configure the compile to support indexing of pointers:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
```

Once you include this directive the original code will compile.

Sadly for you this option isn't available in Delphi 7. You'll need to declare a pointer to array of `DWORD`, and cast to that.

Comment: Nice to know but I'm on Delphi 5

Comment: Delphi 5 or 7. I don't care. neither support POINTERMATH.

Comment: It's not all about you though. Not all future readers will be stuck with Delphi 5/7 whichever it is you happen to have.

Comment: I realize it's not all about me, no need for aggression. some of us  can not afford newer versions. I did say it was nice to know. thanks.

Comment: I wasn't being aggressive. Also, read your previous commment, "I don't care". How does that come across? I'm just explaining why I wrote the answer. It's very hard to read intent into comments. Easy to get it wrong. I tend to write very short and factural comments. People often thing I'm being rude when no rudeness was intended. I don't think your "I don't care" was meant to be rude or dismissive. You just said that you did not care.

Comment: I initially specified tags "Delphi5" / "Delphi7" because I don't care which compiler (Delphi5/7). I have access to both. I did not meant that I don't care about others. you got +1 from me also.